# Qtip and <select> not displaying title

Tags: qtip2

I have the following bootstrap and knockout select:

```
<select title="Select an outbound header column to which the value on the right will map to.  Selecing default will allow you to define a constant value to populate the outbound feed with." 
                                    name="attributeSelect" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="options: $root.ColumnDropdown,
    optionsText: 'PDBColumnName',
    optionsValue: 'PDBColumnId',
    value: SelectedColumn
    "></select>
```

When mousing over the title displays properly however the following qtip doesn't format it properly

```
$('select[title]').qtip();
```

I have this exact same implementation working on the page for check boxes, is there something missing to get this to work with selects?

Comment: `title` is not a valid attribute of `select`. Does qtip have other attribute options?

Comment: I completely forgot that, going to try your suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd maybe use `data-qtip-title` and this:

```
$('[data-quip-title]').qtip({ // get elements with a non-blank data-tooltip attr.
    content: {
        attr: 'data-qtip-title' // look inside this attribute for its content
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7vpP3/2

http://qtip2.com/guides

Comment: Getting a `syntax is not aloud in CSS 3.0` exception on the not equals. Guess I will go through the documentaion, what you have in your fiddle works great but is not working on my end.  I'm using mvc5 with razor.

Comment: You can take that out (see my edit). Maybe use `data-qtip-title` as a more specific selector.

Comment: Still nothing, going to have to do some debugging as this should be working.

Comment: ha that was me just retyping it, sorry i'm running on fumes today.

Comment: Works in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7vpP3/3/ so it has to be something on my end.